# Can I use Terraform to replace an existing Os disk with a managed disk?

Tags: azure, terraform

I wrote the code as follows. For now, the code for creating the vm is omitted here.

1. Take a snapshot of the Os disk you are currently in use.
2. Make the snapshot you created a managed disk.

The code is as follows.

snap.tf

```
# OS DISK -> snapshot
resource "azurerm_snapshot" "tf" {
  name                = "snapshotpspl"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.system_rg_name.name
  create_option       = "Copy"
  source_uri          = "/subscriptions/.../osdisk01"
}

# snapshot -> managed disk
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "copy" {
  name                 = "managed1"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.system_rg_name.name
  storage_account_type = "StandardSSD_LRS"
  create_option        = "Copy"
  source_resource_id   = "/subscriptions/.../snapshotpspl"
  disk_size_gb         = "256"
}
```

I don't know how to replace the managed disk that was created with the VM's OS disk. It used to be possible on azurerm_virtual_machine, but now it's gone. Portal has the ability to swap OS disks. Can't you implement it as a terraform?

I wrote a new code as below and it worked well for me.

disk_snap.tf

```
variable "vm_snap" {
  type = map(any)
  default = {
    snap1 = {
      snap_name         = "osdisk01_snap01"
      snap_option       = "Copy"
      # [1]disk source id
      snap_source_id    = "/subscriptions/.../osdisk01"

      managed_disk_name = "osdisk01-new01"
      managed_disk_type = "StandardSSD_LRS"
      managed_option    = "Copy"
      # [2]Managed source id
      managed_source_id = "/subscriptions/.../osdisk01_snap01"
      managed_size      = "512"
      managed_v_ge      = "V2"
      managed_os_type   = "Linux"
    }
  }
}

## [1] DISK -> Snapshot
resource "azurerm_snapshot" "tf" {
  for_each            = var.vm_snap
  name                = each.value.snap_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.rg
  create_option       = each.value.snap_option
  source_uri = each.value.snap_source_id
}

## [2] Snapshot -> managed disk
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "copy" {
  for_each             = var.vm_snap
  name                 = each.value.managed_disk_name
  location             = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.rg
  storage_account_type = each.value.managed_disk_type
  create_option        = each.value.managed_option
  source_resource_id = each.value.managed_source_id
  disk_size_gb       = each.value.managed_size
  hyper_v_generation = each.value.managed_v_ge
  os_type            = each.value.managed_os_type

  depends_on = [azurerm_snapshot.tf]
}
```

os_disk_swap.tf

```
## swap osdisk -> manageddisk
resource "null_resource" "osdisk_swap" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az vm update --name vm-teset --resource-group tg-test --os-disk /subscriptions/.../osdisk01-new01"
  }
}
```

Does anyone have a better opinion?

Comment: you can use local-exec provisioner.

resource "null_resource" "swap_os_disk" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az vm update --name <VMname> --resource-group <rg> --os-disk ${azurerm_managed_disk.copy.id}
  }
}

Comment: Thank you. With your help, I was able to write a new code. The new code has been reflected.